# Ionic - Push Notifications without firebase or something similar

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, notifications, push

For my diploma thesis I need to find a way to recieve Push Notifications in an ionic app without using fcm or something similar.
So does anybody know a way how I can do this.

My idea is that the ionic app makes a request to the server and asks if there is a new Notification and then displays the notification with the local notifications plugin.

But in this case the problem is that the app has to run to do the request.
Is there a way to "wake up" the app in background every minuten so the app can send the request to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use One signal or aws push
1. https://onesignal.com/
2. https://aws.amazon.com/sns/

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: But the problem is I'm making the programm for a company and the want to implement push notifications without any external service. So is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: if you dont want to use  any kind of push services use a socket either websocket or socket.io to show the action on app but works only on app foreground

Answer (score -2):

You can use SignalR to receive notification for your Mobile application. [here](https://medium.com/@rukshandangalla/how-to-notify-your-angular-5-app-using-signalr-5e5aea2030b2) is the tutorial that how you can implement SignalR into your application. But you need a backend service to listen your database. This tutorial is on Dotnet API.